# Python order Dict with a pre-defined order

Tags: python, json, dictionary, ordereddictionary

Receive a dict and return a new ordered dict

**A json returned from an api:**

```
{
    'host': '192.168.0.1',
    'name': 'my_new_name',
    'port': 443,
    'something_more': 'hello'
}
```

**The goal:**

```
{
    'name': 'my_new_name',
    'something_more': 'hello',
    'host': '192.168.0.1',
    'port': 443
}
```

there is some way where I can define the order of keys?

For example to achieve this order on **goal**:

```
key_order = ('name', 'something_more', 'host', 'port')
```

Thanks

Comment: What version of Python are you using? 3.7 has user-definable dict order, but anything earlier and you might be out of luck.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know about the enumerate method? You could use the enumerate method on the key_order tuple to get the index and element at each index to get values from the json returned by the API.

Comment: Is the goal to print the dictionary that way or actually store it that way?  Basically what are you trying to accomplish with the order?

Comment: @Kevin I'm using python 3.6.3

Comment: @user1234 you just restated what you already said with no additional information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Python 3.7 or later*, you can specify the order of items in your dict, because insertion order is preserved. Create a new dictionary and insert the items in whatever order you like:

```
def reorder_items(d, keys):
    d = d.copy() #we're going to destructively modify d, so make a copy first
    result = {}
    for key in keys:
        if key in d:
            result[key] = d.pop(key)
    #the user might not have supplied all the keys belonging to d, 
    #so insert anything we haven't touched yet
    result.update(d)
    return result

d = {
    'host': '192.168.0.1',
    'name': 'my_new_name',
    'port': 443,
    'something_more': 'hello'
}

desired_key_order = ('name', 'something_more', 'host', 'port')
goal = reorder_items(d, desired_key_order)
print(goal)
```

Result:

```
{'name': 'my_new_name', 'something_more': 'hello', 'host': '192.168.0.1', 'port': 443}
```

(*you can also do this in CPython 3.6, but this is an implementation detail which should not be relied upon)

Prior to 3.7, you can't directly control how items in a dict are ordered. But you can use the `collections.OrderedDict` type. Use the function in the previous code block, switching out `result = {}` with `result = collections.OrderedDict()`.

---

A more concise (albeit slightly opaque) approach is:

```
result = {key:d[key] for category in (desired_key_order, d.keys()) for key in category if key in d}
#or, for versions prior to 3.7,
result = collections.OrderedDict((key, d[key]) for category in (desired_key_order, d.keys()) for key in category if key in d)
```

This takes advantage of the fact that dict comprehensions and OrderedDict can be constructed with duplicate keys, while staying in order in relation to the first appearance of each key.

This is still a little longer than jpp's solution, since it is trying to be a bit more error-tolerant. It works even if `d` contains keys that `desired_key_order` doesn't, and vice-versa. Items whose order is not specified will appear in the result after items that do have a specified order.

Comment: or you could simply do `goal={k: d[k]for k in ('name', 'something_more', 'host', 'port')}` if on 3.7+.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a list comprehension to feed a list of tuples to [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = {'host': '192.168.0.1', 'name': 'my_new_name',
     'port': 443, 'something_more': 'hello'}

key_order = ('name', 'something_more', 'host', 'port')
res = OrderedDict([(k, d[k]) for k in key_order])

OrderedDict([('name', 'my_new_name'),
             ('something_more', 'hello'),
             ('host', '192.168.0.1'),
             ('port', 443)])
```

Works for Python 2.x onwards. For Python 3.7+, you can rely on insertion ordering and use a regular dictionary.

Comment: This solution is preferable over my own if you're certain that `key_order` contains every key that might appear in `d`. If `d` contains keys that `key_order` doesn't, they wont' appear in the result. I went a little out of my way to ensure the result dict is the same size as the input dict, but this may be unnecessary if the input has a reliable and well-known structure.

Comment: @Kevin, Yep, your solution is certainly more general. I implied a bit from OP's example data.

Answer (score 0):

[Ordered Dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects) is the thing you need my friend.]

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d = OrderedDict([
('name', 'my_new_name'),
('something_more', 'hello'),
('host', '192.168.0.1'),
('port', 443)
])
```

Edit: this only works in Python 3.6+. Also feed the `OrderedDict` with a list of tuples instead of a dictionary to maintain the order of key-value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Python <3.7, `OrderedDict` preserves the order of the items:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = OrderedDict([
        ('name', 'my_new_name'),
        ('something_more', 'hello'),
        ('host', '192.168.0.1'),
        ('port', 443)
    ])

# OrderedDict([('name', 'my_new_name'), ('something_more', 'hello'), ('host', '192.168.0.1'), ('port', 443)])
```